# Filter isnoempty mdx

Tags: mdx

I have the following code in OBIEE

```
case when FILTER("- Work"."Actual Labour" USING ("- WorK"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED')) null then 0 else
FILTER("- Work"."Actual Labour" USING ("- Work"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED')) end
```

how to do the same with mdx ,

I try this

```
iif(IsEmpty(FILTER("- Work"."Actual Labour" , ("- Work"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED'))  , 0 ,
FILTER("- Work Orders"."Actual Labour" , ("- Work"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED')) )
```

But it always return `null` .

Answer (score 0):

Square braces are used in `mdx` rather than speach marks:

```
IIF
(
  IsEmpty
  (
    Filter
    (
      [- Work].[Actual Labour]
     ,
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag] = 'SCHEDULED'
    )
   ,0
   ,Filter
    (
      [- Work Orders].[Actual Labour]
     ,
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag] = 'SCHEDULED'
    )
  )
)
```

But your FILTER statements are wrong - you could use this function like so:

```
IIF
(
  IsEmpty
  (
    Filter
    (
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag].members
     ,
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag].currentmember.member_caption = 'SCHEDULED'
    )
   ,null
   ,Filter
    (
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag].members
     ,
      [- Work].[Scheduled Flag].currentmember.member_caption = 'SCHEDULED'
    )
  )
)
```

Looks to me like you need a `WHERE` clause in your `mdx` script like the following:

```
WHERE
 ([- Work].[Scheduled Flag].[SCHEDULED])
```

Comment: how can I add  [- Work Orders].[Actual Labour] in the filter statement ?

Comment: there are several places in an `MDX` script where data can be filtered - can you provide the full script? Subselect and the WHERE clause are 2 other possible places to apply filters to the data without having to use the slow option you have detailed: `FILTER` function plus a string is slow.

Comment: I am looking to convert the expression in OBIEE into MDX .I add it as calculated member . case when FILTER("- Work"."Actual Labour" USING ("- WorK"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED')) null then 0 else
FILTER("- Work"."Actual Labour" USING ("- Work"."Scheduled Flag" = 'SCHEDULED')) end